# Horizontal lift of brownian motion to $S^{2n+1}$.

Tags: differential-geometry, stochastic-processes, complex-geometry

I have a problem, how to obtain a formula for horizontal lift of curve $\gamma$ from $\mathbb{C}P^{n}$ to $S^{2n+1}$, which appears in this paper on page 7:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.06470.pdf  .

What steps I should pass to obtain this formula?

Please for help with my problem.

Comment: It's all laid out very clearly in the paper. The horizontal lift at $z\in\Bbb CP^n$ of a tangent vector $v\in T_x S^{2n+1}$ is the unique vector $\tilde v\in T_z\Bbb CP^n$ with $\pi_*(\tilde v)=v$ satisfying $\eta(\tilde v) = 0$. The authors make all the formulas explicit, so where are you stuck?

Comment: Thank You for Your answer and I'm sorry for late response. Your answer dispel my doubts.